# How to translate taxonomy breadcrumbs?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, breadcrumbs

My breadcrumbs only show in the original language.
When I change the language, only the heading of the breadcrumb which is in a `t()` function changes language. I can't put the `$breadcrumb` variable in the function, the string translation interface is also not the right place for it.
I am using taxonomy menu and taxonomy breadcrumbs modules.
How can I get the breadcrumbs to use either the translated terms or at least work through string translation?

Answer (score 0):

[Taxonomy Breadcrumb](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_breadcrumb) module has maintenance status: Unsupported. It means it's author's answer to all problems with it is simply "stop using it". There is a bug report 2 years 41 weeks old about your problem and I don't really expect it will be fixed any time soon.